# How to undo "sudo chmod 777 /workspace" ubuntu

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ubuntu

I have deployed node.js on aws server using putty. While giving permission to a file which I dont know how to give i used "sudo chmod 777 workspace/". and when i ran my file "index.js" it gives me encrypted data . then I used "sudo chmod 775 workspace/". After a little search i used "sudo chmod -777 workspace/" and then "sudo chmod -775 workspace/" After this when i tried to enter to enter in '/workspace' it gives error 'Permssion denied' so i used "sudo chmod 777 workspace/" again and it gave me access to '/workspace' But again when i ran my file it is encrypted.  So now please tell me how to undo these two commands and give permission to file index.js. Please do not remove this question and help me find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

try `sudo chmod -R 777 ./workspace`

Comment: still the output ic encrypted

Comment: then its not permission issue, its the issue in programming the code

Comment: then try using permission 755

Comment: still everything is encrypted

Comment: /home/ubuntu/workspace/NodeServer/index.js:1
VimCrypt~01!�<�l����Kx7��v=n(���8Y'     j�E3�;j\�a�����kɱϲ}�FBW��<��<��4�U�b�!��E��b����r��OW��'��,YrN��� ��X2�M��s�ò�=�D0��Py��BT����h����; ��E�K37�6
                                                                      ��������V�\�+�F��w��n�J'궼������N∔aP��*N�\ۣK�Z��|&��l�gh��ꐈ2v�zj�;�S�XU���&����pd:Lw �u&��u/��]��y}��8>�
8��o︵�޹�#�R�gK
A/�d����{'N{+l�?c2����!��E��F�d��4U���%�CP�l�^�/�P[h%J�n�S���SL��]C�o"�Ӷ�zX���!1-��&����u� \�����*!c$��?"�|{lT(�NV��2�F���8hjv��K��3��r��

Comment: And beneath SyntaxError: Unexpected token ~
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:872:18)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:947:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:703:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
ubuntu@ip-172-31-4-215:~/workspace/NodeServer$ PuTTY^C

Comment: This is not due to permission issue at all

Comment: then kindly help me to find the issue

Comment: This is node Js syntax error, You have `~` somewhere in code which gives this error

Comment: I tried to edit it and it gives me many errors so i tried but failed to upload it

Comment: but the same code is running perfectly on localhost

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post.  Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24068412).